# Como faço para chamar o campo email da tabela default auth_user?? precisava para fazer o usuarios se registrar com email, usuário e senha

Tags: python, django

meu register.html esta assim

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>

    <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BmbxuPwQa2lc/FVzBcNJ7UAyJxM6wuqIj61tLrc4wSX0szH/Ev+nYRRuWlolflfl" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title>Sistema de cadastramento de Bens</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class ='col-8 m-auto pt-2 pb-2 text-center'>
        <h1>Cidadãos cadastradoos</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
    <div class ='col-8 m-auto pt-2 pb-2 text-center'>
        <a href="/accounts/login/" class="btn btn-info">Voltar</a>
    </div>

        <div class="col-8 m-auto pt-3 pb-2 text-center">
            <div class="card auth-card">
                <div class="card.body">
                    <h4 class="card-title text-center">Entrar no Sistema de Bens</h4>
<form method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}

    <div class="form-group">
        {{form.username.errors}}
        <label>Username: </label><br>
        {{form.username}}
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        {{form.password1.errors}}
        <label>Senha: </label><br>
        {{form.password1}}
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        {{form.password2.errors}}
        <label>Confirmação de senha: </label><br>
        {{form.password2}}
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="submit" value="Cadastrar" class="btn btn-primary">
    </div>
</form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

tentei colocar o email nesse padrão mais nãp foi. Alguém poderia me ajudar??

minha models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
class Cidadao(models.Model):
    nomebens = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    nomecompleto = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    numSerie = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    endereco = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    email = models.EmailField()
    observacao = models.TextField()
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user
```

Comment: mostre como esta a classe modelo, com ela pode reescrever essa parte reutilizar a autentificação do django.

Comment: coloquei no tópico la,

Comment: você estara usando o painel admin do django para adicionar um novo usuario , tendo apenas um super administrador controlando isso?

Comment: esse mail no caso queria tirar, pq não esta relacionado com o a classe User..

Comment: eu queria que o próprio usuário se cadastrasse por isso nâo usei o admin

Comment: Ata, e não tera permissão de grupos?

Comment: não, nao tera nao

Comment: Esta otimo então, tentarei recriar esse problema e explicar o código

Answer (score -1):

Usando function based views.

Criando Formulario:

app usuario, gerenciador de usuario

```
  #app usuario
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.models import User # utilizando autentificacao 


class NovosuarioForm(forms.Form):
usuario = forms.CharField(required=True) #campos que seram requisitados
email = forms.EmailField(required=False)
senha = forms.CharField(required=True)


def is_valid(self): # verif se o formulario é valido

    formularioValido = True # inicia como true...

    if not super(NovosuarioForm, self).is_valid():
        print("preencha todos os campo") # caso for preenchido apenas o nome sem senha retornara invalido
        formularioValido = False

    #query que ira verificar se ja existe o usuario com mesmo nome
    novo_usuario = User.objects.filter(username=self.data['usuario']).exists()

    if novo_usuario: # apresenta uma mensagem  avisando que usuario existe
        print("usuario ja cadastrado")
        formularioValido = False # ou pode excluir, e evitando duplicata no model

    return formularioValido
```

Como ira usar o User, não precisa do model, pois ira reutilizar os campos da tabela do django.

view do usuario

```
    # app usuario VIEW...
from django.shortcuts import redirect
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.views.generic.base import View
from perfis.models import Perfil # aplicação do usuario
from usuarios.forms import NovosuarioForm # gerenciador de usuario

#Duas aplicacões, A do usuario e um gerenciador de novos cadastros
#então um startap usuarios, que vai gerenciar
# outro startap que sera o perfil cadastrados

class RegistrarView(View):


def get(self, request): #get retorna a formulario
    return render(request, "criarLogin.html")

def post(self, request):# add dados
    form = NovosuarioForm(request.POST) # do app usuario

    if form.is_valid(): # verif se é valido
        dados_form = form.data 
        #variavel usuario puxa de User que cria usuario usando o form especificado 
        usuario = User.objects.create_user(dados_form['nome'],
                                           dados_form['email'], dados_form['senha'])
        # do model pefil, salvara o nome 
        perfil = Perfil(nome=dados_form['nome'],
                        usuario=usuario)

        perfil.save() #feito ,agora salva

        return redirect('ja_foi_adicionado.html')

    return render(request, "algumtemplate.html", {'form': form})
```

MODEL perfil:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class Perfil(models.Model):
    nome = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=False)
    usuario = models.OneToOneField(User, related_name="perfil", on_delete='NOTHING')
```

O template de registrar novo usuario e login ficam dentro do app "usuario"

```
<form method="post">

    {% csrf_token %}

    <input type="text"name="nome">
    <input type="text"  name="email">  
    <input type="password" name="senha" >

   

    <button type="submit" value="Login">

</form>
```

URLS DO USUARIO

```
from django.urls import path
from usuarios.views import RegistrarView
from django.contrib.auth import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('cadastrar/', RegistrarView.as_view()),
    # e os path de login e logout
]
```

Urlpatterns

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('perfil.urls')),
    path('', include('usuarios.urls'))
]
```

O setting:

```
LOGIN_URL = '/login/'
LOGOUT_URL = '/logout/'
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/'


INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'perfil',
    'usuarios'
]
```

view perfil

```
from perfis.models import Perfil, 
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

    @login_required
    def get_logado(request):
        return request.user.perfil
```

caso queira outra referencia:

[simpleisbetterthancomplex.com](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2017/02/18/how-to-create-user-sign-up-view.html)

Comment: a primeira e a segunda parte do codigo é no view.py ??

Comment: o utilirario, RegistrarView é do usuario, devo ter me confundido, e o view do perfil apresenta se o usuario esta logado.
a uma view no app usuario e no perfil que indicara que foi logado.